# randomly add between 1 and 180 minutes to an existing datetime value in SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, random

We have a large table with two datetime columns, starttime and endtime.  endtime is not populated. starttime has data. We would like to populate endtime like this:

```
         update t
         set endtime = DateAdd(mi, some random int between 1 and 180, starttime)
```

Can that be done in T-SQL, so that a varying number of minutes is added, i.e. all the rows don't have the same number of minutes added to the starttime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can generate a random number for each row by using a CHECKSUM / NEWID() approach:

```
UPDATE t
SET endtime = DATEADD(mi, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 180, starttime)
```

Comment: This is a good answer, and a bit easier to remember than RAND. Either way, since a version number of SQL Server was not specified, be aware of this: [Change in Behavior of RAND and NEWID in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/change-in-behavior-of-rand-and-newid-in-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 0):

```
update t
set endtime = DateAdd(mi, CAST( RAND()*1000 AS INT)  % 180, starttime)
```